# Is there any way of creating the map and also navigating the environment together i.e. continuously?

Tags: slam, navigation, mapping, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello All,

So in my Final Year Project, I am constructing a robot which creates a map of an unknown environment while traversing the environment using the map (so an autonomous map making robot) basically, both the tasks being implemented together and not creating the map first and then navigating using the map while avoiding obstacles. Is there a way to do both the tasks together? Please help I am really struggling...

Thank you,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285311/is-there-any-way-of-creating-the-map-and-also-navigating-the-environment-together-i.e.-continuously?/) by [hasnain](https://answers.ros.org/users/33864/hasnain/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-03-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sounds like you're describing [frontier exploration](http://wiki.ros.org/frontier_exploration).

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ruffsl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5234/ruffsl/) on 2018-03-13**:
link should be http://wiki.ros.org/frontier_exploration (with underscore)

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-03-13**:
Thanks. For some reason the copy and paste of the URL didn't work out right

**Comment by [hasnain](https://answers.ros.org/users/33864/hasnain/) on 2018-03-23**:
Doesn't it require manual instructions in terms of where to start and where to go?